# Undefined symbols for architecture i386, only on iPad simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocoapods

There is a framework imported via *CocoaPods* named *JPush* in my project.

Everything was just fine on iPhone device and iPhone Simulator. But the complier kept complaining the following when I switched to iPad simulator (I didn't try it on iPad devices because I didn't have any iPad with me).

[image]

I gathered all iOS devices architecture

```
arm64：iPhone6s | iphone6s plus｜iPhone6｜ iPhone6 plus｜iPhone5S | iPad Air｜ iPad mini2(iPad mini with Retina Display)
armv7s：iPhone5｜iPhone5C｜iPad4(iPad with Retina Display)
armv7：iPhone4｜iPhone4S｜iPad｜iPad2｜iPad3(The New iPad)｜iPad mini｜iPod Touch 3G｜iPod Touch4

32-bits processor:
simulator: i386
real device: armv7 or armv7s
64-bits processor: 
simulator: x86_64
real device: arm64
```

So when you come up with the same error, try use `file FILENAME` command to show what architecture your static lib supports.

Comment: i think this error cames from derive data so got to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData clear derivedata folder and run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework you're trying to link against doesn't include an i386 slice:

```
libjpush-ios-3.0.9.a: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures: [arm_v7:current ar archive] [arm64]
libjpush-ios-3.0.9.a (for architecture armv7):  current ar archive
libjpush-ios-3.0.9.a (for architecture armv7s): current ar archive
libjpush-ios-3.0.9.a (for architecture x86_64): current ar archive random library
libjpush-ios-3.0.9.a (for architecture arm64):  current ar archive
```

It does include an x86_64 slice, though. Select a 64-bit iOS device for simulation (iPhone 5S or later) and rebuild.

Comment: Wow! How did you find those info? BTW, I just want to test my project on iPad. My project is iPhone only but I still should test it on iPad in case of the bad UI layout, right?

Comment: @JsW Apple always test in iPad to check your iPhone only app work in iPad or not. So, you should test it on iPad too.

Comment: I ran the `file` command on the library. What iPad model did you target for your build? Try choosing one of the newer models.

Comment: @duskwuff Got it! I figured it out! The 32-bits simulators run on i386 and the 64-bits simulators run on x86_64. So I change the simulator to iPad Air, which feels like a 64-bits simulator. Thanks, buddy!